# ack=all and min ISR

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

If my producers have ack=all and ISR is 2 and partitions is 2 what is the scenario ?

Comment: spell mistake *scenario Explain the process , means How producer write the data in kafka topic partitions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of partitions is irrelevant to the acks setting. The producer will (always) write to the leader partition (pre-determined by the client partitioner).

When you set acks=all, then it'll block and wait for every replica of the record to be written across the cluster using the replication factor of the topic, not ISR setting.

The ISR setting only determines when a topic is unavailable due to brokers being offline, and doesn't affect the producer.